# RestRequest works in Postman but gives 403 Forbidden error in C#

Tags: c#, postman, restsharp

I'm using RestSharp to get an response of an url in C# but is always giving an 403 Forbidden error. In Postman it works fine and I'm getting an 200 Success. Here's my code in C#:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://data.fei.org/Calendar/ShowDetail.aspx?p=17C909D981B698168E94ACB4EB1963B1");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("postman-token", "45b65980-83be-7d2f-a60d-e1238dbd9417");
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

What I'm doing wrong to get this error?

[Postman image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awBwV.jpg)

Comment: Is this a console application?

Comment: No it's a WindowsFormsApp

Comment: Have you used Fiddler to compare the Postman requests and the C# requests to see what the difference is?

Comment: The website is checking user agents (I just checked by using a fake useragent with https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg). Postman is using a browser user agent, so the website serves up content. You will need to overwrite the user agent (https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/787).

Comment: I've added an image of the postman send and download

Comment: You're not authorized to see that page, make sure you logged in correctly and have the right cookies/xsrf headers etc

Comment: @johnny5 see my earlier comment.